# What are the real advantages of immutable collections?

Tags: scala, data-structures, functional-programming, immutability

Scala provides *immutable* collections, such as `Set`, `List`, `Map`. I understand that the immutability has advantages in concurrent programs. However what are exactly the advantages of  the immutability in regular data processing?

What if I enumerate `subsets`, `permutations` and `combinations` for example? Does the *immutable* collections have any advantage here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What are exactly the advantages of the immutability in regular data processing?

Generally speaking, immutable objects are easier/simpler to reason about.

Comment: Which enables tools (i.e. compilers) to do more optimizations

Comment: I agree, and it means using immutable objects produces code that is more often correct first time. Along with static typing, this makes Scala code require remarkably little debugging.

Comment: @michid - So far I have found hundreds of cases where mutable implementations are faster (if harder to reason about), and only a handful where any tool I know of can make more optimized code.  I think you are either overestimating in practice how much optimizers can do, or underestimating how clever they are with supposedly mutable operations.

Comment: Mutable things are perfectly easy to reason about if for every aspect of any object's state which might ever change there never exists more than one entity that regards that aspect of the object's state as being part of its own state.  Unfortunately, frameworks which use promiscuous object references often make it hard to maintain that invariant.

Answer (score 7):

It does. Since you're enumerating on a collection, presumably you'd want to be certain that elements are not inadvertently added or removed while you're enumerating.

Immutability is very much a paradigm in functional programming. Making collections immutable allows one to think of them much like primitive data types (i.e. modifying a collection or any other object results in creating a different object just as adding 2 to 3 doesn't modify 3, but creates 5)

Comment: That's a very interesting comment - it seems like that gives you "transaction-like" semantics on your data, i.e. if you do `for((k,v) <- myMap){something(k,v)}` and someone does `myMap += k2 -> v2` down inside `something`, you'll still be iterating over a snapshot of what `myMap` had when you started the loop.  Right?  I never thought about that.

Answer (score 6):

To expand Matt's answer: From my personal experience I can say that implementations of algorithms based on search trees (e.g. breadth first, depth first, backtracking) using mutable collections end up regularly as a steaming pile of crap: Either you forget to copy a collection before a recursive call, or you fail to take back changes correctly if you get the collection back. In that area immutable collections are clearly superior. I ended up writing my own immutable list in Java when I couldn't get a problem right with Java's collections. Lo and behold, the first "immutable" implementation worked immediately.

Comment: I hope you didn't write that immutable list implementation anytime too recently, since we've had [`Collections#unmodifiableList()` (Java SE)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) and [`ImmutableList` (Google Guava)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) for a while.

Comment: `unmodifiableList` isn't useful at all, e.g. you can't get a list with an additional element back or so. Guava is cool, but sometimes overkill. The best immutable list implementation I know is from http://functionaljava.org

Answer (score 4):

If your data doesn't change after creation, use immutable data structures. The type you choose will identify the intent of usage. Anything more specific would require knowledge about your particular problem space.

You may really be looking for a subset, permutation, or combination generator, and then the discussion of data structures is moot.

Also, you mentioned that you understand the concurrent advantages. Presumably, you're throwing some algorithm at permutations and subsets, and there's a good chance that algorithm can be parallelized to some extent. If that's the case, using immutable structures up front ensures your initial implementation of algorithm X will be easily transformed into concurrent algorithm X.

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple advantages to add to the list:

1. Immutable collections can't be invalidated out from under you

   That is, it's totally fine to have immutable public val members of a Scala class.  They are read-only by definition.  Compare to Java where not only do you have to remember to make the member private but also write a `get` method that returns a copy of the object so the original is not modified by the calling code.
2. Immutable data structures are persistent.  This means that the immutable collection obtained by calling `filter` on your `TreeSet` actually shares some of its nodes with the original.  This translates to time and space savings and offsets some of the penalties incurred by using immutability.

Answer (score 0):

some of immutability advantages :

1 - smaller margin for error (you always know what’s in your collections and read-only variables).

2 - you can write concurrent programs without worrying about threads stepping on each other when modifying variables and collections.